# Finding payoff matrix for guessing game

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, game-theory

I'm trying to solve this game theory problem:

> Player A and B, each take out one or two matches and guess how many
>   matches the opponent has taken. If one of the players guesses
>   correctly, then the loser has to pay him as many rupees as the sum of
>   the number held by both players. Otherwise, the payout is zero. Write
>   down the payoff matrix and obtain the optimal strategies of both
>   players.

I came up with this game matrix. For each strategy *(a,b)* *a* is the number of matches taken by the player and *b* is the player's guess.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    & (1,1) & (1,2) & (2,1) & (2,2)\\
    (1,1) & 0 & 2 & -3 & 0\\
    (1,2) &-2 & 0 & 0 & 3\\
    (2,1) & 3 & 0 & 0 & -4\\
    (2,2) & 0 & -3 & 4 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
The game has no saddle point and there are no dominated rows or columns. I put the matrix in [this](https://cbom.atozmath.com/CBOM/GameTheory.aspx?q=lpp&q1=0%2C2%2C-3%2C0%3B-2%2C0%2C0%2C3%3B3%2C0%2C0%2C-4%3B0%2C-3%2C4%2C0%60A1%2CA2%2CA3%2CA4%60B1%2CB2%2CB3%2CB4%60lpp%60true&dm=D&dp=4&do=1#PrevPart) solver and  got the optimal strategies as *(0,0,0,0)* for each player.

Am I doing something wrong?